# What would be a pattern for a general row of an identity matrix?

Tags: pattern-matching

I know this is a novice question but I would like a pattern for a list containing zero or more zeros followed by exactly one 1, followed by zero or more zeros.  Something like:
    {0___,1,0___}

But specifying that 0 must be zero.

Comment: I think what you want is `..` and `...` that is `Repeated` and `RepeatedNull` rather than `Blank` and its friends.

Comment: Yes, thanks to Carlo and Micahal E2. I am using this to build a row reduction method without loops.

Comment: When using patterns, beware of the difference between `1` and `1.` or `0` and `0.`.  Generally, you can also use `/;` and specify an arbitrary condition in patterns, e.g.`row_ /; Count[row, 1] == 1 && Union[row] == {0, 1}` (not necessarily the best solution for this particular problem).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I believe you're looking for [`RepeatedNull`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/RepeatedNull.html)

```
Count[IdentityMatrix[10], {0 ..., 1, 0 ...}]
(* 10 *)
```